# NPM : Cannot find module 'node-gyp/bin/node-gyp'

Tags: node.js, npm, ubuntu-14.04, npm-install, node-gyp

I'm using **NPM** under my **ubuntu 14.04** and **node 8.0.0** .

I have upgraded my **npm** from **5.2.0** to **5.6.0**

but after that all npm commands are failing , indicating a problem of :

> node-gyp/bin/node-gyp

The complete log is the following :

```
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'node-gyp/bin/node-gyp'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/khalidvm/.npm/_logs/2018-01-12T15_02_35_338Z-debug.log
khalidvm@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ gedit /home/khalidvm/.npm/_logs/2018-01-12T15_02_35_338Z-debug.log
^C
khalidvm@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ sudo npm uninstall npm -g
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module 'node-gyp/bin/node-gyp'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/khalidvm/.npm/_logs/2018-01-12T15_05_25_322Z-debug.log
```

I'm afraid that I'm not able to use npm , even uninstalling it, throws that same error.

Comment: I m having the same problem. How did you solve this?

Comment: @ManeeshGautam , i ve resistalled the whole node.js and npm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're running the default installation of node on Ubuntu 14.04, the package should be out of date (I believe it's a 0.xx version) and be the source of your problems. You can fix that by looking here: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

Working with an up-to-date distribution of node, I had the same problem with `node-gyp`. It turned out that I had a *ghost* installation under `/usr/local`. That was ghosting my `node` executable.

After deleting it by running:

```
  sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/node-gyp 
  sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npm
  sudo rm -rf /usr/local/bin/npx
  sudo rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

and cleaning node files in my home directory, for precaution:

```
  rm -rf ~/.node-gyp/
  rm -rf ~/.npm/
```

I uninstalled the current node installation, and reinstalled:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Comment: Thanks @spac ! It's the only answer that works for me!

Comment: Thx @spac, I had the same problem, this is the only solution that worked for me !  I had a lot of trouble debugging and this answer saved me a lot of trouble !

Answer (score 6):

For me (Arch Linux) it was enough to install node-gyp via pacman:

```
sudo pacman -Sy node-gyp
```

For Arch see: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/any/node-gyp/

```
sudo apt-get install node-gyp
```

For Ubuntu see: https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/trusty/web/node-gyp

Answer (score 2):

Also on Arch Linux, for me, it worked when removed nodejs and dependencies and reinstall node and npm.

```
sudo pacman -Rcns nodejs
sudo pacman -S nodejs
sudo pacman -S npm
```

extra good stuff [here](https://linuxhint.com/remove_package_dependencies_pacman_arch_linux/).